# How to parse a vector drawable pulled out from server to View?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

In general vector drawables are compiled, and accessed with their ids in execution time.

My project consist of pulling out images from a server. For now, i'm doing it for png files, but i would try it with vectors ".xml".

I'm able to download those, but i can't parse them in drawable type to show them in views.

How can i do this with a bunch of bytes representing the vectors resources and parsing them to drawables ?

It would be a huge thing for my app since it will be much much lighter, and good for those pixelized pictures.

Comment: Any solution for this query? i also expecting the same

Answer (score 1):

The [inflate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable#inflate(android.content.res.Resources,%20org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) method may be helpful, but you could use a third party library:[androidsvg](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/). Don't reproduce the wheel if possible.

Comment: I already parse svg files to the corresponding vector drawable resource. But this resource is not on my project, but in the server. I m pulling it in a byte array, so i need to convert this to a vector drawable.

Comment: The "inflate" method is not really public. Instead, maybe use VectorDrawable.createFromStream instead, but still I don't get how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

If you can access the image from the server via url, use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load it to your View. By so doing, you don't have to download the image to your storage before using it in an `ImageView`. However, if you still want to get the image as a byte array and display it in a view, use the code snippet below...

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/yourimage.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); //This is the image byte
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT); //Encoded string
```

Furthermore, you can convert the string to a `Bitmap` and then pass it to your `ImageView`.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Let me know if you have any question concerning this, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: This is not exactly what im looking for. I need to parse byte arrays representing a vector drawable to a vector drawable.

Comment: This is not about a simple bitmap. It's about VectorDrawable.

Comment: Can you answer the question with the right answer then? @androiddeveloper

Comment: @DevMike01 Sadly no. I tried various functions of VectorDrawable and its compat version too. Maybe I'm doing something wrong ...:(